# Calling a parameterized constructor using 'this' instance

Tags: c#

```
class manning
{
    public  int i = 0;
    public manning() : this(this.i) or this(i) //why is this not possible.
    {
        this.i++;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    public manning(int i)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

In the above code while calling the parameterized constructor why can't I use 'this' keyword as the way it is declared.

It actually gives me an error stating that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" which can be resolved by making `i` `static`, but `i` is initialized when constructor is invoked using new.

Please help me understand why above code is not possible.

Comment: It's not possible because the language standard says it's not. This could be *made* possible by assigning semantics to it, but what would be the point? Combining initializers and constructors is confusing enough as it is. Initializers are implemented by gathering them up in lexical order and making them part of the constructor. Now try figuring out how that should work out if they're passed as arguments to another constructor.

Comment: "Now try figuring out how that should work out if they're passed as arguments to another constructor."
@JeroenMostert wht do u mean,can u give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is what creates an instance of the class, so it makes sense you wouldn't have access to it's members before it's been created,

From the example you've shown you'd always be putting 1 into the base constructor, because that variable will always be it's default value.  To accomplish the equivalent you'd just have to call

```
manning() : this(1)
```

But I doubt that is what you actually want,
I think your confusing this with using a static variable

**NOTE:** since your calling your base constructor there is no reason to duplicate the logic in the constructor

```
public class manning
{
    public static int i = 0;
    public manning() : this(i) 
    {
    }
    public manning(int i)
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Your class isn't created yet so you wont have access to the instance, 2. It makes no sense, your instance variable will always be initialized to 0 and you're just adding 1 to it so you will always be passing 1 to the base.

Comment: Because the instance of member variable i does not exist until after construction

Comment: The flow is a bit complex, you can read more up on it [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx), static variables have a different life timethan the instance members, to generalize they're around for the life of your programs(or around the first attempt to access that class)

Comment: @leaner does this answer you question, please mark this as resolved by  clicking the empty check